# Security Voter call from repository/querybuilder

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

After reading [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) i dont understand how to implement voter to multiple entities.

My voter is working for one entity when i do this :

```php
/**
 * @Route("/entity")
 */
class EntityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="entity_show", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function show(Entity $entity): Response
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(EntityVoter::VIEW, $entity);

        return $this->render('entity/show.html.twig', [
            'entity' => $entity,
        ]);
    }
}
```

How i can implement this voter for "index" ? I can browse every element and call voter but there are maybe a better/cleaner solution ?

```php
/**
 * @Route("/entity")
 */
class EntityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="entity_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(EntityRepository $entityRepository): Response
    {
        //here i need to do something with EntityVoter
        return $this->render('entity/index.html.twig', [
            'entitys' => $entityRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to use voters to select entities to display ?

Comment: So instead of checking the ACL for every entity in a loop you're looking for i.e. a custom voter using a single/more-optimized query? Add your current `EntityVoter` implementation to the question please.

Comment: @MinDBreaK yes, my "EntityVoter" is a copy/paste from doc "PostVoter", and i trying to add an "VIEW" attribute and i want use this voter to display entities

Comment: @NicolaiFröhlich my "EntityVoter" is a copy/paste from doc "PostVoter.
Yeah i can use a query but if my voter change i need to change query too.
I'm going to try to implement this with querybuilder

Comment: Voters are not realy designed to be used for DB but more about access to a page. It is your job to keep in sync those 2 places. You could create a static method that would add in your query builder those conditions, but the voter can't be used in DB in an efficient way. Bonus point : That would ruin any attemps to paginate anything.